# How can I restrict data entry for an array of cells if the prior cell has not been populated?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a user form for work where the user can select up to 15 clients from a list using excel data validation. However, I only want the second cell to be available to populate once the first has been populated, and the third when the second is populated etc. I also want the color of the cell to change when it becomes available to populate

I've tried using regular excel data validation and conditional formatting, but it seems limited in that I would have to create a separate data validation for each cell, rather than making one data validation command for the entire range

I would think using an if(IsEmpty) would solve my problem but as a fairly new VBA user I am having trouble determining the most efficient way to incorporate the list data validation into the general entry restriction.

Comment: When you say user form you mean you are making data validation lists in the spreadsheet itself?  User Form means something different to the folks at SO, that would be a form that is called to show in a window.  Google this "validation dependent lists" and "conditional formatting" try a few things out.  The folks on the forum know excel tricks but mostly concern themselves with the "code behind vba".  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Listboxes are what you want in your form if you go the VBA route.

Comment: Thanks @Wookies-Will-Code and for the verbiage tip! I guess I wasn't totally clear - I have been toying with the excel validation and conditional formatting tools but think they are too limited which is why I was trying to figure out if VBA would be more useful. I thought maybe I could use VBA to my existing form in excel but I will give a list box in a VBA user form a try.